# Is this JList setSelectedIndex repaint issue a bug in OpenJDK 8?

Tags: swing, jlist, repaint, java

I've implemented an auto-completion dialog. It consists of a text field and a JList of completion proposals. I wanted to make it scrollable by arrow keys, but without loosing focus in the text field so the user can always narrow down the list.

But I've encountered a repaint issue.

Good vs bad ([also see video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_m-XuBZeJcg)):

[image] [image]

The most interesting part is that this seems to be a problem with OpenJDK 7 and 8. When I use Oracle JDK 8 it works fine. Could this be a bug in JDK? Could anyone verify if they get the same result? Or is my code wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.Runnable;

public class CompletionSelectionDialogRepro extends JDialog {
    private JTextField compInput;
    private JList<String> complOptions;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CompletionSelectionDialogRepro dialog = new CompletionSelectionDialogRepro();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public CompletionSelectionDialogRepro() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 250, 304);
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);
        {
            compInput = new JTextField();
            compInput.setText("");
            springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, compInput, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
            springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, compInput, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, getContentPane());
            getContentPane().add(compInput);
            compInput.setColumns(10);
        }
        {
            complOptions = new JList<String>();
            complOptions.setModel(new AbstractListModel<String>() {
                String[] values = new String[] {
                    "<html>somename<u>xt</u></html>" , "<html>auauau<u>xxxxxx</u></html>",
                        "<html>othername<u>xt</u></html>" , "<html>barfoo<u>xt</u></html>",
                        "<html>yetother<u>xt</u></html>" , "<html>foobar<u>xt</u></html>" };
                public int getSize() {
                    return values.length;
                }
                public String getElementAt(int index) {
                    return values[index];
                }
            });
            springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, complOptions, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, compInput);
            springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, complOptions, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, getContentPane());
            springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, complOptions, -10, SpringLayout.EAST, getContentPane());
            complOptions.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
            getContentPane().add(complOptions);
        }

        compInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
              @Override
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                  if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                      e.consume();
                      arrowPress(-1);
                  }
                  else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                      e.consume();
                      arrowPress(1);
                  }
            }
        });

        complOptions.setFocusable(false);
    }


    protected void arrowPress(final int dir) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ListModel<String> listMod = complOptions.getModel();
                if (listMod.getSize() > 0) {
                    int i = complOptions.getSelectedIndex();
                    complOptions.clearSelection();
                    if (i == -1)
                        i = 0;

                    i += dir;

                    if (i < 0)
                        i = listMod.getSize() - 1;
                    if (i >= listMod.getSize())
                        i = 0;

                    complOptions.setSelectedIndex(i);
                    complOptions.ensureIndexIsVisible(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommend wrapping the GUI code in `main` within `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Works for me using Oracle JDK8 on Windows 7. Could be a platform issue? `Or is my code wrong?` Don't know if it will make a difference but Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) not a KeyListener.